# WordPress Multisite, NGINX and WordPress Subdirectory Install

Tags: multisite, nginx

I'm attempting to set up WordPress skeleton (https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton/) in a multisite configuration. WordPress skeleton already places WordPress in a subdirectory (wp by default). I've taken the following steps:

- git clone WordPress-Skeleton
- Update Submodules and checkout 3.6.1 tag
- Setup local-config.php to point to my local DB Install WordPress, set
  site settings to example.com (site), example.com/wp (WordPress URL)
- Configured multisite (subdirectory) and configured NGINX to serve the
  Multisite properly (NGINX config can be found here:
  https://gist.github.com/tmort/6582961)

Once all of this is configured, I can see that the main site (example.com and example.com/wp/wp-admin) both work.

I then add a new site to the network. Upon navigating to the site url (example.com/test-network-site) the front-end is broken (style.css, for example, cannot be found at the URL http://example.com/wp/test-network-site/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/style.css?ver=2013-07-18). When navigating to the wp-admin, I'm in a redirect loop.

My end goal is to be able to use WordPress Skeleton as a base for the sites I deploy and have the multisite configuration work as it does normally (where example.com is the network main site, example.com/test-network-site is a site within the network, and example.com/test-network-site/wp-admin works as it should). At this point my main question may be is this even possible?

I have a good feeling that the NGINX configuration is the main issue as (for fun) I created the exact same environment locally and fired up MAMP. Under MAMP, this configuration works fine.

Unsure of how to move forward. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Compare with [Nginx: Multisite Subdirectory rules](http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx#WordPress_Multisite_Subdirectory_rules) ?

Comment: You can install WordPress Multisite(Subdomains and Subdirectories) with nginx just by using easyengine (http://goo.gl/Wzidcu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might check in **General Settings**:

- Home URL should be `http://example.com`
- Site URL should be `http://example.com/wp`

When you open `http://example.com`, what URL does it show for `…/twentythirteen/style.css`?

Do you see the "broken" URL

`http://example.com/wp/test-network-site/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/style.css`

in the source? If so, it suggests WordPress might be using a wrong path (not necessarily nginx).

I **think** that should be

`http://example.com/test-network-site/wp/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/style.css`

You might check if that URL works at all.